# Javascript shift and replace value on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which the values are :

**[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]**

if triggered by change the select an option, let's say I select an option which the value is "**istirahat**" at 2nd row then become empty string but after empty string the number is keep sequence like my screenshot :

[image]

in this case it's solved by this funtion :

```
 function add(array, index, value) {
        array.splice(index, 0, value);
 }
```

the function above is works like what i expect:

```
1
-
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

BUT I've new case that if I select an option which values is "**pelajaran**" the number that missing 
will be back and replaced the empty string, I've try with this script :

```
 $(document).on('change','.jenis_mapel', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() == "istirahat") //get val of select option (istirahat condition)
    {
        add(arr,index,'')
        var col1;
        var num = 0;

        $('.tb_senin tr').find('td:eq(0)').each(function() { //loop the arr value to first column (jam ke column)
            col1 = $(this).text(arr[num]);
            num++;
        });

        console.log(arr);
    }
    else //(other condition, that the number should be back)
    {
        var tbRow = $('.tb_senin tr').length - 1;
        if (arr[index] == "") {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
        console.log(arr);
    }
});
```

The Bug is when I select "**istirahat**" at 2nd row and 3rd row , the array would be like this

**[1, "", "", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]**

when I removed index 1, it's become like this (which i selected option **pelajaran** at 2nd row , index 1 of the array ) : 
**[1, "", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]**

Which I expected the output like this :

```
1 
2
""
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Why only `2` comes before an empty string?

Comment: because I selected option value "istirahat" at 3nd row of the table (which in array is index 2 right ?)

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood your problem.

Here is your reproduced bug:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

// You click on the second row and one empty item is added.
var clickedIndex1 = 1;
add(arr, clickedIndex1, '');
log(arr);

// Now when you click a different row you are checking if 
// the row contains empty string and if is the case ONLY then 
// you will remove the empty string. This is the BUG
var clickedIndex2 = 3;
if (arr[clickedIndex2] == "") {
    arr.splice(clickedIndex2, 1);
}
log(arr);

// And because you have not clicked on the empty row
// the empty item was never removed. So when you click on 
// another row, a new empty item is added.
const clickedIndex3 = 2;
add(arr, clickedIndex3, '');

// And you have the same result as you have shown us.
log(arr);


function add(array, index, value) {
   array.splice(index, 0, value);
}

function log(arr) {
  // Just for logging horizontally the array.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

And here is how you fix it:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

// You click on the second row and one empty item is added.
var clickedIndex1 = 1;
add(arr, clickedIndex1, '');

// You have to keep track of last empty item added 
var lastEmptyIndex = clickedIndex1;

log(arr);


// Now when you clicked on another row, you don't need to 
// check if is empty anymore. You will just remove the stored empty index
var clickedIndex2 = 3;
arr.splice(lastEmptyIndex, 1);

log(arr);

// Now you have your initial array and the new empty will be added 
// at the good position. let's say you have clicked on 4th row
const clickedIndex3 = 3;
add(arr, clickedIndex3, '');
log(arr);


function add(array, index, value) {
   array.splice(index, 0, value);
}

function log(arr) {
  // Just for logging horizontally the array.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

Therefore in your code you can do something very similar to what I have shown you in my mocks:

```
var lastEmptyIndex = null; // <----------------- INIT HERE
$(document).on('change','.jenis_mapel', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() == "istirahat") //get val of select option (istirahat condition)
    {

        if (lastEmptyIndex) {
          arr.splice(lastEmptyIndex, 1);  // <-------------- Here reset (you can add this if in a function...)
          lastEmptyIndex = null; 
        }

        add(arr,index,'');
        lastEmptyIndex = index; // <------------------ HERE
        var col1;
        var num = 0;

        $('.tb_senin tr').find('td:eq(0)').each(function() { //loop the arr value to first column (jam ke column)
            col1 = $(this).text(arr[num]);
            num++;
        });

        console.log(arr);
    }
    else //(other condition, that the number should be back)
    {
        var tbRow = $('.tb_senin tr').length - 1;

        if (lastEmptyIndex) {
          arr.splice(lastEmptyIndex, 1);  // <-------------- Here
          lastEmptyIndex = null; 
        }

        console.log(arr);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've try your solutions but still not working , plz look my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vo0yt6eL/

Comment: Ok, I'm trying it now

Comment: @Aaron you have to add the same if in your first condition as well: Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/3xyrto68/1/

Comment: hemm your fiddle, the empty string only works on 1 element of array ... what i expect actually like this https://jsfiddle.net/vo0yt6eL/1/ (I almost solved it, but it's still has bug which if i selected the input select from bottom up , the number doesn't sequence anymore :( )

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what is the behavior/logic of the app you want. Could you reexplain in simple words what the app should exactly do? Should the id be sequencial for all rows except the `istirahat`?

Comment: yes, u're right ... the rows should be sequence except `istirahat` ... but not id,the sequence should on column `jam ke`